# In Civ V, what happens when you take a city in a One City Challenge Game?

Tags: civilization-5

In Civ V, what happens when you take a city in a One City Challenge Game?  Clearly keeping the city would be a huge advantage, so I would be surprised to hear that you are allowed to keep and use the city.  Is it automatically razed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It razes the city automatically, see [this thread](http://forums.2kgames.com/forums/showthread.php?t=90964) on the official forums.

Answer (score -2):

The city is razed automatically. Otherwise, it would be a huge advantage and not a challenge since cities are easy to take, especially city states.

Comment: This doesn't provide any new information